# How to automatically serialize and deserialize JSON string using JPA and Hibernate?

Tags: json, hibernate, jpa, orm, jackson

I have data class/table "User" that has column "preferences"

```
CREATE table "user"; 
ALTER TABLE "user" ADD COLUMN preferences TEXT;
```

Preferences type is TEXT and I am storing JSON there.

```
public class User extends AbstractEntity{
public String preferences;
}
```

so `user.preferences` value is `"{notifyByEmail:1, favouriteColor:"blue" }"`

How can I wrap it with some annotation so I can access it like

```
user.preferences.notifyByEmail
```

or without need to wrap into data object

```
user.preferences.get("notifByEmail");
user.preferences.set("notifByEmail",true);
```

I imagine there could be some Jackson annotation that I can add to field
like

```
@JsonGenerate
public String preferences;
```

I am fairly new to JPA and documentation is steep.

I believe my case is quite common. Can anyone give any examples?

Comment: What's the rationale to want to store this data as JSON Strings and not separate, distinct fields (Here, of types boolean and enum)?

Comment: Rationale being I don't want to support every key-value preference as separate field.

Preference key:values are growing and hanges and there's quite a lot of them. changing model or adding field to database for each of them is an overkill.

Comment: Have you then considered using an attribute table to story the values? The use case is indeed common, but your proposed solution is not quite fitting into a relational model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Honestly I think your best solution is to create a separate table (preference) for your properties.

```
+------------+
| preference |
+------------+---------+------+-----+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key |
+------------+---------+------+-----+
| user_id    | bigint  | NO   | PRI |
| key        | varchar | NO   | PRI |
| value      | varchar | NO   |     |
+------------+---------+------+-----+
```

You can map this in your entity like this:

```
@Entity
public class User
{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "key")
    @Column(name = "value")
    @CollectionTable(name = "preference",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    private Map<String, String> preferences;
}
```

This way your database is more normalized and you don't have to fool around with 'creative solutions' like storing preferences as JSON.

Comment: Thank you for providing comprehensive description. I will try it!

Comment: This does not do it the way the question requested it.

Comment: @HiramChirino I do not see anything wrong with providing an alternative to the questioner. Especially when an alternative may provide a better solution. The questioner seemed satisfied with this solution (helpful), the answer isn't effortless or incorrect so I don't see any reason to vote down. Please [see the help pages on when to vote down](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down), for the sake of Stackoverflow.

Comment: So THAT's how this is done. The way I read how those mapping annotations were used always lead me to believe this type of key-value storage was impossible under JPA. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

Can achieve this using JPA Converter.

Entity;

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
Long id;

@Column(name = "mapvalue")
@Convert(converter = MapToStringConverter.class)
Map<String, String> mapValue;
```

Converter:

```
@Converter
public class MapToStringConverter implements AttributeConverter<Map<String, String>, String> {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Map<String, String> data) {
        String value = "";
        try {
            value = mapper.writeValueAsString(data);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> convertToEntityAttribute(String data) {
        Map<String, String> mapValue = new HashMap<String, String>();
        TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>> typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {
        };
        try {
            mapValue = mapper.readValue(data, typeRef);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mapValue;
    }

}
```

Saving data :

```
Map<String, String> mapValue = new HashMap<String, String>();
mapValue.put("1", "one");
mapValue.put("2", "two");
DataEntity entity = new DataEntity();
entity.setMapValue(mapValue);
repo.save(entity);
```

The value will store in DB as

```
{"1":"three","2":"two"}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's very easy to persist JSON objects using Hibernate.

> You don’t have to create all these types manually, you can simply get
> them via Maven Central using the following dependency:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
>     <artifactId>hibernate-types-62</artifactId>
>     <version>${hibernate-types.version}</version> 
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> For more info, check out the [Hibernate Types open-source project](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-hibernate-types-open-source-project-is-born/).

### For Hibernate 6

The entity mapping will look like this:

```
@Type(JsonType.class)
@Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
private String preferences;
```

### For Hibernate 5

You need to add this `@TypeDef` annotation on the class level or in a **package-info.java** package-level descriptor to use the [`JsonType`](https://vladmihalcea.com/map-string-jpa-property-json-column-hibernate/) Hibernate Type:

```
@TypeDef(
    name = "json",
    typeClass = JsonType.class
)
```

Afterward, the entity mapping will look like this:

```
@Type(type = "json")
@Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
private String preferences;
```

That's it!

Comment: Hi Vlad, I'm extensively using TypeDefs and TypeDef annotations and I want to upgrade to hibernate 6. Can you edit this answer by providing a solution that would work with hibernate 6.2?

Comment: Good idea. I added a section for Hibernate 6.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need something like that the most recommendable is to do the next:

```
public class User extends AbstractEntity{
  @JsonIgnore //This variable is going to be ignored whenever you send data to a client(ie. web browser)
  private String preferences;

  @Transient //This property is going to be ignored whenever you send data to the database
  @JsonProperty("preferences") //Whenever this property is serialized to the client, it is going to be named "perferences" instead "preferencesObj"
  private Preferences preferencesObj;

  public String getPreferences() {
    return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(preferencesObj);
  }

  pbulic void setPreferneces(String preferences) {
    this.preferences = preferences;
    this.preferncesObj = new ObjectMapper().readValue(preferences, Preferences.class);
  }

  pubilc Preferences getPreferencesObj() {
    return preferencesObj;
  }

  public void setPreferencesObj(Preferences preferencesObj) {
    this.preferencesObj = preferencesObj;
  }
}
```

Additional Notes:

- Maybe the private property "preferences" could be deleted and only use getter and setter.
- I haven't test that code.
- The above code is intended to use Jackson ObjectMapper and Hibernate module.

Comment: can u please provide the example of JSON Array as well. I ve been struggling deserializing JSON Array with annotaion.

Comment: Would this not require a Class called `Preferences` which needs all the different preferences that a `User` can have?

Comment: yes. If you prefer something dynamic, you better use a map instead.